# How to set SVG viewBox width/height to the max x/y value of child elements

Tags: svg

I am dynamically generating SVG content in Python, which will be displayed in a browser. I can resize perfectly using preserveAspectRatio and hard-coded viewBox values like

```
<ns0:svg xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg-content"
height="200px" preserveAspectRatio="xMidyMid meet"
version="1.1" viewBox="0,0,3500,3500" width="200px" x="0px" y="0px">
```

But the child elements are sometimes dynamically placed beyond (3500,3500). Can viewBox take attributes somewhat like

```
viewBox="0,0,auto,auto" # (set to include all child elements)
```

Or do I have to manipulate these values with Javascript or Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manipulate them programmatically.  There is no "auto" setting for viewBox.

However, since it sounds like you know the position and size of the objects you are adding, it should be straightforward to keep track of the min and max X and Y coords, so you can derive the minX, maxX, width and height values for the viewBox.

Answer (score 0):

a [viewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) can only take 4 numbers as its arguments.